# Rails STI associations and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a structure like the following:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
end

class BulkOrder < Order
  has_many :vehicles, inverse_of: :order

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicles
end

class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :vehicles
end
```

Now when I try to create the model along with the associated attributes, Rails gets confused and the Vehicle model gets an error that Order doesn't have an association named "vehicles". This is true – it doesn't – but if Rails were to actually deduce the proper type of the Order, it would get a BulkOrder, and see that it does indeed have this association.

Btw, I don't want to move the has_many association up to Order because not all Orders will have Vehicles. I also don't want to specialize as `belongs_to :bulk_order`, because other orders will have Vehicles as well (although not all of them).

Another issue is that associated attributes tries to set "bulk_order_id" on Vehicle, instead of "order_id".

Any ideas?

Comment: you could specify the `foreign_key` as `order_id`

Comment: You mean something like `belongs_to :bulk_order, inverse_of: :vehicles, foreign_key: 'order_id'`, right? I tried this, did not work either.

Comment: `accepts_nested_attibutes_for` was still trying to set `bulk_order_id`, if I recall.  I even overrode `bulk_order_id=` so that it set the `order_id` as a sort of proxy, but then I got another issue, which I don't recall right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to add `has_many :vehicles` to Order. And then remove the contents of BulkOrder since it inherits from Order.

Adding the has_many property to Order will not mean that all orders will have vehicles. It simply allows vehicles to belong to an order, as in it allows each vehicle to be have an order_id. And if you haven't already, add order_id to vehicles.
`$rails g migration add_order_id_to_vehicles order_id:integer`

Comment: Damn, yeah it's kind of a hack, but there may be no way around it. Right now what I did was add `has_many :vehicles` to `BulkOrder`, and also changed the foreign key to `bulk_order_id`. Of course, this leads to more foreign keys as I add more subclasses that can have vehicles, so I will likely switch to your solution once this becomes evident.